# Google Apps Script error - multiple rows from Google Sheets but only one file in Google Drive - "iterator has reached the end"

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a script that pulls fields from a Google Sheet and inserts them into an email template and sends the emails off. That works fine.

I recently wanted to include a PDF as an attachment to the emails. It would be the same PDF for every email. I uploaded the PDF into Google Drive. When I run the script, the first email is sent off fine with the attachment but the following emails are not sent because I encounter this error: "Cannot retrieve the next object: iterator has reached the end"

Pretty sure it has to deal with the attachment/file and me not handling the iteration correctly. Can someone help? Below is the code:

```
function send2Email()
{
  var filename= 'even_overview2020.pdf';
  var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
  
  var spread         =SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  var contactSheet   =spread.getSheetByName(contactSheetName);
  var bodySheet      =spread.getSheetByName(templateSheetName);
  var contactData    =contactSheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var bodyData       =bodySheet.getDataRange().getValues();
  var fname,company,sign,template,email,subject,body,sender,file;
  for (var i =1;i<contactData.length;i++)

  {
    contactData[i][statusCol-1]="";
  }
  contactSheet.getDataRange().setValues(contactData);
  for (var i =1;i<contactData.length;i++)
  {
    fname=trim_(contactData[i][fnameCol-1]);
    company=trim_(contactData[i][companyCol-1]);
    sign=trim_(contactData[i][signCol-1]);
    template=trim_(contactData[i][templateCol-1]);
    email=trim_(contactData[i][emailCol-1]);
    sender=trim_(contactData[i][senderCol-1]);
    Logger.log(email);
    for(var j=1;j<bodyData.length;j++)
    {
      if(trim_(bodyData[j][tempRefCol-1]).toUpperCase()==String(template).toUpperCase())
      {
        body=bodyData[j][bodyCol-1];
        subject=bodyData[j][subjectCol-1];
      }
    }
    Logger.log(j+","+email+','+body+','+subject);
    body=body.replace(/\n/g,"<br>");
    body=body.replace("(w)",sign).replace("(x)",fname).replace("(y)",company).replace("(s)",sender.split(" ")[0]);
    Logger.log(email+','+body+','+subject);

    
    MailApp.sendEmail({to:email,subject:subject,name:sender,htmlBody:body,attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
    contactSheet.getRange(i+1, statusCol).setValue('Y');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about this modification?

### Modification point:

- In your script, `attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]}` is used in the loop. By this, the 1st loop works by `file.next()`. But after 2nd loop, an error occurs at `file.next()` because the file of `filename` is one file in Google Drive. I think that this is the reason of your issue.

In order to avoid this issue, how about the following modification?

### Modified script:

#### From:

```
var file = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
```

#### To:

```
var files = DriveApp.getFilesByName(filename);
var file;
if (files.hasNext()) {
  file = files.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF);
} else {
  throw new Error("No file");
}
```

And also, please modify as follows.

#### From:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to:email,subject:subject,name:sender,htmlBody:body,attachments: [file.next().getAs(MimeType.PDF)]});
```

#### To:

```
MailApp.sendEmail({to:email,subject:subject,name:sender,htmlBody:body,attachments: [file]});
```

### Reference:

- [Class FileIterator](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/drive/file-iterator)

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! That worked perfectly. I really appreciate you taking time to help me.

Comment: @Eric Chen Thank you for replying. I'm glad your issue was resolved. THank you, too.